# How to "broaden" an IPv6 to the network level?

Tags: mysql, ip

I have IP addresses stored in a MySQL database and as I'm learning to run queries, one thought I had was to see if I could find entries that share a common network. To do this, I "broaden" my search by removing the last group of numbers from an IPv4.

So I'll do a `LIKE` search for an IP of `XXX.XX.XXX.` and see what comes up.

I have two questions:

1. Is what I'm doing stupid? Like, does trimming off the last group even achieve what I think I'm doing?
2. If not, how would I "broaden" a search for IPv6?

I've done some research on the groupings of IPv6, but I'm afraid I'm still not understanding what each grouping does. Admittedly I have only cursory knowledge of the anatomy of even IPv4.

Again, this isn't really a serious issue, but I couldn't find any information about something like this (which is what leads me to believe that I may not even be doing what I think I am doing)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is what I'm doing stupid? Like, does trimming off the last group even achieve what I think I'm doing?

To answer that first requires some definition of what it means to "share a common network".  After all, the Internet itself is a "common network" that is "shared" by every device connected to it!

Network engineers tend to talk in terms of "domains": [collision domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_domain), [broadcast domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_domain), [administrative domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_domain), etc.  At a guess, you might be thinking in terms of administrative domain.

For [a short time in history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network), a chunk of the IP address space (known as "Class C" addresses) were assigned such that the first three octets indicated the network number, and therefore "trimming off" the final octet would (for that chunk of the IP address space) have behaved exactly as you describe.

However, since the introduction of [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), it no longer works like that: addresses can now be assigned in any (2-exponent) size of block and you cannot determine the size of the allocated block from the address alone.  Moreover, blocks can be repeatedly subdivided and reallocated.

**TL;DR—it's not clear what you think you're doing but in any event trimming off the last group probably doesn't achieve it.**

Now, if you only want to determine whether a given address is on *your* network you can do so by performing a bitwise AND between it and *your* network mask; then comparing the result with the bitwise AND of *your* address and *your* network mask.

Beyond that, you'd need to lookup properties of the address in external datasets...